# Invalid License data .Reinstall is required C# 2010 Express

Tags: c#, licensing

I Downloaded Microsoft C# 2010 Express and install
but aftre Open The Program i have this message
Invalid License data .Reinstall is required

I [ Windows 8.1 ]

Comment: Not sure about Express, but my MSDN version of VS2013 gave me a similar error message.  I had to re-enter the MSDN license key.  I guess Windows 8.1 did something to mess up the registration information.  Did you re-install?

Comment: i try re-install the program But is there a way to change License data

Comment: Do you need such an old version?  VS 2015 Community is free and much newer https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx